# How I can typeset a footer on only one page?

Tags: header-footer

Does anyone know how I can make \rfoot at only 1 page.

I am using report as document class, and in my preface I want my name and city at the right side at the bottom of the page

Comment: The solution may to depend on the document class you're you using? Consider editing your question to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I am using report as document class, and in my preface I want my name and city at the right side at the bottom of the page

Comment: Is your preface consisting of what is also known as a frontmatter, or are you talking about the title page?

Comment: just the title page

Comment: You can also have a look at [How to customize a titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907).

Answer (score 18):

This is a more conventional method...

Define a new page style

```
\fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[R]{Alim, from Unknown City}}
```

and use

```
\thispagestyle{alim}
```

only in the page where you want the right foot, e.g. the title page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[R]{Alim, from Unknown City}}
\pagestyle{fancy} % or whatever

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{alim}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Yes, with the help of commands from the [`atbegshi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) package.

If you want the `\rfoot` only in the first page, use this code in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \rfoot{Alim, from Unknown City}%
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
    \rfoot{}%
  }%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \rfoot{Alim, from Unknown City}%
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
    \rfoot{}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Instead, if you want the `\rfoot` only in a page which is not the first (let's suppose page 2), use this code in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1%
    \rfoot{Alim, from Unknown City}%
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
      \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
        \rfoot{}%
      }%
    }
  \fi%
}
```

Change `1` to `3` if you want it, for example, on page 4.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1%
    \rfoot{Alim, from Unknown City}%
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
      \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
        \rfoot{}%
      }%
    }
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but i think it is a bit overkill here ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I know. But this answers the question in all possible cases...

Answer (score 6):

My feeling is that you shouldn't place content in the *footer* if it forms part of your title page. Instead, just place it at the bottom of the text block, aligned according to your needs. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{50pt}% Similar to a regular \chapter gap
  \centering% Horizontal centred content

  \Huge My title% Title

  \huge Some subtitle% Subtitle

  \bigskip

  \LARGE My name% Name

  \Large Something else about me% Something else

  \bigskip

  \large \today% Date

  \vfill% Vertical fill to go to the bottom of the page

  \hfill\normalsize My name, My City% Right-aligned name/city
\end{titlepage}

\blinddocument% Rest of document

\end{document}
```