# Change header on a specific page

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

(hoping that neither my reviewers nor anybody in my field is going to read this) I would like to put an easter egg in my Ph.D. thesis (written using the amazing classicthesis template). I would like to change the header of page 42  with *Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything* instead of the default section title. Is it possible to do so? I understood that it is possible to change the header at some point of the tex (by for example using `fancyhdr` and defining a `pagestyle`), but can I address exactly page 42 no matter what content is into it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Add an if-condition in header? It then checks whether it is P42 everytime.

Comment: This might help http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220800

Comment: Hi and welcome, out of pure interest: How long are you using `classicthesis`? You seem to be the first one that isn't annoyed by the this badly and outdated template.

Comment: Hi @Johannes_B ! I started approximatively a month ago. I experienced a number of problems (some of which are still present, like a significant number of bad hyphenated lines), but I kinda like it :) Is there anything better to your knowledge? Honestly, I did not do a thorough research, so probably there are better choices out there.

Comment: Right now i am in some kind of holy war concerning templates. There is some kind of misunderstanding due to a lack of common nomenclature or misused terms. `classicthesis` (the original template) used KOMA-script for its great functionality (according to the doc of ct); but right at the same time broke several KOMA-stuff due to questionable implementation. IMHO it needs a complete fix along with some tidying up.

Comment: Have a look at Nicola Talbots [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) which introduces you to LaTeX in general and the KOMA-classes specifically. There is a volume two: [Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html). You should just use the bits and pieces you need that ct provides, check if its gone obsolete and maybe search for modern alternatives. For example, the original template uses a not really up to date bibliography management.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` in your header. For example this changes the header on page 3 with the `classicthesis` definitions:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,pagesize,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\newcommand{\replaceText}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything}}
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}\ifnum\value{page}=3\replaceText\else\headmark\fi\hfil}}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\ifnum\value{page}=3\replaceText\else\headmark\fi}\rlap{\small\kern2em\thepage}}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext[60]
\end{document}
```

OLD ANSWER if you are not using `classicthesis`:

You can use an `if` in your header. For example this changes the header on page 3:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\ifnum\value{page}=3{Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything }\else\headmark\fi}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```