# Changing either the header or page number of a single page?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

Maybe a bit unoriginal, but I'd like to change a single page number or header on a page (page 42 in this case) to say "*Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything*". 
If the number is changed, it should be without disrupting the page numbering, so 43 follows this page. This is for my Ph.D. dissertation, and I'm using the `PhDThesisPSnPDF` template.

I found a veeery similar question/answer, but the template was different enough that I couldn't get it to work ([Change header on a specific page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226327/change-header-on-a-specific-page))

I'm also not very Latex savvy, so a layman's answer would be appreciated!

Comment: If you've found the answer useful, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

My personal take on this is the following.

The [`PhDThesisPSnPDF`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/master/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls) class has three different page styles. Since you didn't mention any of them, I'll assume you're going to use the default one.

Looking in the `.cls` file, the page style is defined with `fancyhdr`, so we can borrow the definition of the default style and adapt it to your needs.
The desired outcome at page 42 is obtained with a simple conditional

```
\ifnum\value{page}=42{<print the HG2G sentence>}\else <does nothing> \fi
```

Since the HG2G sentence is very long, on page 42 I changed the header to print it in place of the `\leftmark`.
In the default style, the `\leftmark` is the title of the chapter.
In this way, the sentence title will not overlap with the chapter title.

From the MWE below, you have to copy in your preamble the page style

```
\fancypagestyle{hg2g}{
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth {##1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase \rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bfseries\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{
        \ifnum\value{page}=42{Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything }\else {\nouppercase \leftmark} \fi
    }
}
```

and then use it with the `\pagestyle{hg2g}` command.

If compiled, the MWE will produce three pages, starting from page 41; the second page will be page 42, with the header you wanted.

```
\documentclass{PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\fancypagestyle{hg2g}{
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth {##1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase \rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bfseries\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{
        \ifnum\value{page}=42{Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything }\else {\nouppercase \leftmark} \fi
    }
}
\pagestyle{hg2g}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{41} % only for this MWE, remove it from the tex file of your thesis
\chapter{Use of towels}
\newpage
You can wave your towel when writing your PhD thesis as a distress signal!
\newpage
\section{Stay warm with a towel}
\end{document}
```

I'm pasting only the screenshot of the header:

[image]

Another important assumption is that chapters will begin only on odd pages. The class is based on the `book` class, which has this behavior by defautl. That said, you should *not* use the `openany` option, that allows chapters to begin on even pages.
Should a chapter begin on page 42, you'd lose the effect, because the pagestyle in this case does not print the page number.